# Customising debian linux code

Tags: linux, debian

My current openmediavault implementation suffers from a few faults and the current one is how to move my downloaded files from the downloaded folder to a disk which is set aside speciically for that purpose.
I don't know much about linux but I have customised the TV part. The movies section is more difficult for my skill sets:

```
cd "$FOLDER_PATH"

####################
# Movie Processing #
####################

if [ $CATEGORY_NAME = "movies" ]
then
        # Where do you want to put the movies that this script processes?
        MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=" /media/6f1b1b52-a404-4bb7-a249-382b25b75801/Movies/"

        MOVIE_NAME=`echo $FOLDER_NAME | sed 's/ (.*)//g'`
        echo "Movie Name: $MOVIE_NAME" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs

        if [ `find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | wc -l` -eq 2 ]
                then
                FILEZ[1]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sort | sed -n '1p' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                FILEZ[2]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sort | sed -n '2p' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                echo "Joining Files..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                mencoder -forceidx -ovc copy -oac copy -o "$FOLDER_PATH/$MOVIE_NAME".avi "${FILEZ[1]}" "${FILEZ[2]}"
                #Get the path for the avi
                FILEZ[1]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                echo "Making Folder..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                #Make Folder for the avi
                mkdir "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME"
                echo "Moving Files..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                #Move the avi to the folder
                mv "$FOLDER_PATH/$MOVIE_NAME.avi" "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME/$MOVIE_NAME.avi"
                #If there's an nfo, move that into the folder as well
                        if [ `find . -regex '.*/.*\.nfo' | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
                                then
                                FILEZ[2]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -regex '.*/.*\.nfo' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                                mv "${FILEZ[2]}" "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME/$MOVIE_NAME.nfo"
                                chmod 777 -R "${MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY}"/"${MOVIE_NAME}"
                        fi
                rm -r "$FOLDER_PATH"  
                echo "Removing Folder: $FOLDER_NAME..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                else
                        if [ `find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
                                then
                                #Get the path for the avi
                                FILEZ[1]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +629145600c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                                echo "Making Folder..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                                #Make Folder for the avi
                                mkdir "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME"
                                echo "Moving Files..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                                #Move the avi to the folder
                                mv "${FILEZ[1]}" "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME/$MOVIE_NAME.avi"
                                #If there's an nfo, move that into the folder as well
                                if [ `find . -regex '.*/.*\.nfo' | wc -l` -gt 0 ]
                                        then
                                        FILEZ[2]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -regex '.*/.*\.nfo' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                                        mv "${FILEZ[2]}" "$MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$MOVIE_NAME/$MOVIE_NAME.nfo"
                                        chmod 777 -R "${MOVIE_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY}"/"${MOVIE_NAME}"
                                fi
                                rm -r "$FOLDER_PATH"  
                                echo "Removing Folder: $FOLDER_NAME..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                        else
                                echo "Couldn't copy(too many files or no files?)" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                        fi
        fi
fi

#################
# TV-HD Processing #
#################

if [ $CATEGORY_NAME = "TV-HD" ]
        then

        echo "Beginning TV Processing..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log

        ##Where is your root TV directory? This script will create folders in it, i.e. ROOT_TV/Seinfeld/Season 8/...
        TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=" /media/6f1b1b52-a404-4bb7-a249-382b25b75801/TV-HD"

        if [ `echo $FOLDER_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print NF}'` -ne 3 ]
                then
                echo "Folder name incorrect, quitting..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log
                exit 0
        fi
        OPT_NAME=`echo $FOLDER_NAME | sed 's/ (.*)//g'`

        SHOW_NAME=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $1}'`


        echo "Show Name: $SHOW_NAME" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log
        SEASON_NUMBER=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $2}' | awk -F "x" '{print $1}'`
        echo "Season Number: $SEASON_NUMBER" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
        EPISODE_NUMBER=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $2}' | awk -F "x" '{print $2}'`

        if [ `find . -size +73400320c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
                then
                FILEZ[1]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +73400320c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                echo "One file found, making directories..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                mkdir "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME"
                mkdir "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME/Season $SEASON_NUMBER"
                echo "Moving File..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                mv "${FILEZ[1]}" "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME/Season $SEASON_NUMBER/$OPT_NAME.avi"
                echo "Removing Folder..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                chmod 777 -R "${TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY}"/"${SHOW_NAME}"
                rm -r "$FOLDER_PATH"
                else
                echo "Couldn't copy(too many files or no files?)" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
        fi

#################
# TV-SD Processing #
#################

if [ $CATEGORY_NAME = "TV-SD" ]
        then

        echo "Beginning TV Processing..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log

        ##Where is your root TV directory? This script will create folders in it, i.e. ROOT_TV/Seinfeld/Season 8/...
        TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY=" /media/6f1b1b52-a404-4bb7-a249-382b25b75801/TV-SD"

        if [ `echo $FOLDER_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print NF}'` -ne 3 ]
                then
                echo "Folder name incorrect, quitting..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log
                exit 0
        fi
        OPT_NAME=`echo $FOLDER_NAME | sed 's/ (.*)//g'`

        SHOW_NAME=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $1}'`


        echo "Show Name: $SHOW_NAME" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs/sab_proc.log
        SEASON_NUMBER=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $2}' | awk -F "x" '{print $1}'`
        echo "Season Number: $SEASON_NUMBER" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
        EPISODE_NUMBER=`echo $OPT_NAME | awk -F " - " '{print $2}' | awk -F "x" '{print $2}'`

        if [ `find . -size +73400320c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
                then
                FILEZ[1]="$FOLDER_PATH`find . -size +73400320c -regex '.*/.*\.avi' | sed 's/^\.//'`"
                echo "One file found, making directories..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                mkdir "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME"
                mkdir "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME/Season $SEASON_NUMBER"
                echo "Moving File..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                mv "${FILEZ[1]}" "$TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/$SHOW_NAME/Season $SEASON_NUMBER/$OPT_NAME.avi"
                echo "Removing Folder..." >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
                chmod 777 -R "${TV_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY}"/"${SHOW_NAME}"
                rm -r "$FOLDER_PATH"
                else
                echo "Couldn't copy(too many files or no files?)" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
        fi



        echo "Done!" >> /home/sabnzbd/.sabnzbd/logs
```

Comment: The formatting on your link is off in your question. Also, what are you trying to do? I see a shell script for categorizing movies (I think based on the file name, but it's a bit hard to follow).

Comment: I am not a Linux person. I am trying to get the script to go through a folder and move the relevant sub-folders to the appropriate folders which are Movies, TV-SD and TV-HD. The download folder is : /media/0fdb085d-2371-4cc6-86f1-0f98e7e3721a/Downloads/Downloads and from this folder, the script should move the contents to the follwoing folders as appropriate:

Comment: /media/6f1b1b52-a404-4bb7-a249-382b25b75801/TV Shows/TV-SD whilst Tv-Hd goes to : /media/6f1b1b52-a404-4bb7-a249-382b25b75801/TV Shows/TV-HD

Comment: The script is here: http://pastie.org/10821513